# Bash programming Quick Search and Extract Method

Tags: linux, bash

I have a very long string with multilines which could consist of over 1300 words.

**EDIT: I want to search and extract roughly two values from the string and store into a variable for formatting and additional processing.**

I can turn the string into an array and loop the lines and search each line by

```
while read -r line; do
            arr+=("$line")
    done <<< "$ACSCH"

    for i in "${arr[@]}"
    do
            if [[ "$i" =~ "level 1: src="(.*)$ ]]; then
                    SRC=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            fi
            if [[ "$i" =~ "level 1: dst="(.*)$ ]]; then
                    DST=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            fi
    done
```

I know I can also just search the string by:

```
if [[ "$ACSCH" =~ "src="([[:alnum:]]*) ]]; then
    SRC=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

but I dont know how to search for the additional variable

The only method I can think of is just putting in another if search on the whole string

```
if [[ "$ACSCH" =~ "DST="([[:alnum:]]*) ]]; then
    DST=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Is that the correct way to do it or is there a better way?

Which way would be faster; breaking into a Loop and searching each line for my variables, my other method, or another method that I do not know about as of yet and that is why I am looking for help here.

**EDIT:
Sample INPUT: ........ src=19r4345e3e some other text in between dst=1kje3dkj35 rest of text of unknown length

Sample OUTPUT: SRC=19r4345e3e | DST=1kje3dkj35

Then I can further process my SRC and DST variables.**

Thanks!
--E

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I dont want to add the smaple input because it is a large text variable. I supplied the sample output above

Answer (score 1):

When you want to find the strings "word1", "word2", "string with spaces and word3" and "word4", you can use:

```
echo "$ACSCH" | grep -Eo "word1|word2|string with spaces and word3|word4"
```

When you have more words to look for, consider the grep option `-f`.

Comment: That doesnt help me - I believe - I want to be able to store the return patterns back into variables not just echo to the shell

Comment: And what do you want to do with the vars?
You can assign them to an array or use a `while read -r line` and assign each line to a var with `printf var$i "%s" "${line}"; ((i++))`